# Changing MyApp-Info.plist gives an error

Tags: objective-c, ios, info.plist

I've added this lines to my app .plist using TextEdit. I would enable iTunes file sharing with:

```
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<string>YES<string/>
```

It results in this error: "couldn't parse contents of '/Users/me/Desktop/MyApp/MyApp-Info.plist': Encountered unexpected character s on line 31"

I wrote it after the other keys and before

```
</dict>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `<string/>` to `</string>` and you should be good